# Vue-CLI to create Vue + Ts project, then meet build error

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I used Vue-CLI to create Vue + Ts project, but I encounter an error when I use npm run build, here is the Error. I do have some types of Error in my project because I used a plugin vue-horization that plugin has no types, however, it's working fine in my dev service.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle web@0.1.0~prebuild: web@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: web@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/apple/Desktop/vue2Web/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
9 verbose lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Users/apple/Desktop/vue2Web
10 silly lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle web@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: web@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid web@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/apple/Desktop/vue2Web
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error web@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the web@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```